# Can the series be the Fourier series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-series

How can one show that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\text{cos}(nx) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\text{sin}(nx)$ can not be Fourier series of any $2\pi$-periodic continuous function?

The series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\text{cos}(nx)$ is a Fourier series of its sum as it converges uniformly. So the problem appears when we add $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\text{sin}(nx)$, but I have no ideas how to prove that an appropriate function does not exist.

Comment: See Theorem 7.2.2, (3), p 112, of Fourier series by Edwards.

Comment: The coefficients are not square-summable.